# inserir dados numa planilha excel

Tags: vb.net

Necessito de inserir dados num ficheiro excel e estou a utilizar o **infragistics.documents.excel** para isso.

necessitava de saber como vejo qual é a ultima coluna com indice  - No caso desta imagem seria o URL   [image: No caso desta imagem seria o URL]

necessitava também de inserir os dados na tabela sendo que os mesmos são armazenados numa **Private Function** dentro de uma data table

o modo como se guarda os dados para os mesmos serem guardados é da seguinte forma

```css
Using t As New DataTable
                da.Fill(t)

                For Each Row In t.Rows
                    Dim e As New ExportLine
                    e.Url = String.Format(Url, Row!ClienteId)
                    e.Nome = Row!Nome
                    e.Telemovel = Row!Telemovel
                    lExportLines.Add(e)
                Next
            End Using
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolvi com

```
`For Each dados In lExportLines

        oWorksheet.Rows.Item(iRow).Cells(iCol).Value = dados.Nome

        iCol += 1I
        oWorksheet.Rows.Item(iRow).Cells(iCol).Value = dados.Telemovel
        iCol += 1I
        oWorksheet.Rows.Item(iRow).Cells(iCol).Value = dados.Url
        iCol = 1I
        iRow += 1I

    Next`
```